# web forms application storing data offline using sqlite

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, linq-to-sql, offline

I have an asp.net web forms application that uses a sql server 2005 on a remote server. 
All controls are bound using linq to sql.

I am trying to provide full offline functionality, so I was wondering if I could create an sqlite database just like the sql server db, install it on users device and then when connection is lost or user wants to work offline, I change binding to the sqlite database?
I imagine I would download all user information to the sqlite db when the user first logs in and then synch later.

Will this allow the datacontrols to still function properly when offline, specifically on a mobile device?

I have looked into local storage, etc., but I need to allow a user to work offline all day if they need to. Also, I would have to make major changes to the whole program which is not an option.

My requirement is to make this asp.net web forms application work offline without significant changes.

I have converted the application from asp.net 2008 to 2010 and now to 2012.

I have 3 months to complete this conversion and that includes learning whatever technology is chosen. It is a large application, so it is not much time.

Any suggestions would great.

I would also like to know what you think about the proposed sqlite database.

Thanks

Comment: Sound too complicate - the html5 have an offline way - but you need to make synchronize some how and this is the tricky part.

Comment: Don't I have to use html controls in order to use html5 offline?  This is a business application that uses a lot of data.  Would the sqlite binding on a mobile device work with asp.net controls.

Comment: You can't make a web application offline without implementing it all over on the client side, because the device wouldn't even have the ability to connect on the web forms application, so all the controls that run on the server wouldn't even execute, moving to a SqlLite database wouldn't help, because it would have to be stored on the client, and therefore you will need to have client code to access it. It is a big deal, you would have to implement the controls logic on both the Server and Client side.

Comment: I found the following post http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2011/01/26/creating-html5-offline-web-applications-with-asp-net.aspx 
which has to do with creating a manifest file.  Thus far I have change my linq to sql to linq to entities and am in the process of building a repository, moving code behind to the repositories. I needed to store a lot of data offline and my understanding is that sqlite works on the majority of mobile devices. 
Eventually this project will be transferred over to mvc, but for now, I was hoping not to have to change out controls.  Any other ideas?

Comment: If I have to change a lot are there any tools out there to help.  What would be the best path to take.  Eventually everything will be client side, but if there are tools that will help me do the conversions that would be a big help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just not possible. You can't force your web forms app which runs in a browser to access a local database at the client side.

Somehow then, to fulfill your requirements, you'd have to change the architecture of your app OR provide an additional, separate channel for offline working. The additional channel could be an html5 app using the local storage, a Silverlight client using one of client-side Silverlight databases like Sterling or even a win forms ClickOnce app using any database available at the client side.

Comment: Will silverlight work on all devices?  What is the ClickOnce app?

Comment: Silverlight will work on Windows machines. ClickOnce is a desktop app deployed automatically from the server.

Comment: If I change out all controls to html controls and use the repository I'm building to pass data to the controls, can I still use a web forms application just nothing bound?  I know MVC would be better, but it's just me and I don't have the time to learn an additional technique right now

Comment: Sheri, repositories run at the SERVER side! It doesn't matter how you organize your server-side code, if the client goes offline, it will not be able to execute the server code. Note also that the server side is done in C# and there is really NO WAY to have this running in a web browser. We understand your requirements but you cannot jump over some existing constraints.

Comment: My intent is when the user logs on and is connected to the internet, all that users data for the current day will be downloaded into a client side database, maybe local storage, since you say sqlite won't work. The user will then be able to work offline if they choose or if they lose internet connection it will still work offline.  The repository will hold my code behind and the way I'm setting it up, it will manage the data either on-line or offline.
If necessary I will move to MVC, but I have 3 months and I don't know mvc well enough yet to implement.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have found this site which uses asp.net web forms and a manifest.  http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2011/01/26/creating-html5-offline-web-applications-with-asp-net.aspx.
I feel so scattered now, I just need a good plan so that I can begin to execute it.

Comment: It's a start, but it doesn't really cover everything you'll need. You'll have to implement some sort of local storage logic for the offline page to use, and probably a lot more javascript to update the UI with the storage data covering every possible interaction that could be done if it was online. I think it will be very difficult to achieve.

Comment: It makes since I would have to use client side script and implement the logic to store data using local db.  I was really hoping to be able to use a relational database when offline, but guess that is not an option. I know their are some client binding options out there, just not sure where to look.  I found http://meteor.com/ who has a library that may work.  They do have a windows version for development.  I am going to look at more.

Comment: After more research I decided the best thing to do was convert the site over to MVC.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Sheri Trager: You may be oversimplifying the synchronization scenario. If this is a single-user application where the user has exclusive control over her data, you only have to merge the offline changes with the server. But if it's a multi-user application, where other users could be changing data while someone is working offline, you have to deal with concurrency issues. The offline user might be attempting to update a row that is fresher than her own; she might be attempting to insert a new row that would violate a uniqueness constraint or some other higher-order business rules.

Comment: @Sheri Trager: comment continued due to length restrictions. You would need to design an interface to let the remote user know which of her inserts, additions, and deletions failed when synching the disconnected dataset with the mothership. For these reasons working with a disconnected database is better suited for situations where users "own" their data than it is for multi-user applications. The synch process can introduce great confusion and it requires savvy users to succeed when a team of users has insert, update, and delete rights on the data.

Answer (score 3):

With regards to offline working in the browser, you might want to check out the following HTML5 apis:

- [AppCache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) (loads all the files required from the server, so that the site will start up even if the server is not available).
- [IndexedDb](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/).  This allows offline data storage, persistent across multiple browser sessions.

In your described architecture above, you in addition to installing sqlite, or some such local database separate from the browser, you would also need to provide a local "server" component (or other such windows service) that the browser was able to communicate with to enable the communication between the browser and the database.

The following diagram shows and example that **would** work, **but you would be re-inventing what is already built in HTML5**:

[image: Example architecture]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is even possible.  First, your web application would need a server to run on just to display the page.  Then you would need a local database for it to connect to.  Syncing them would not be difficult.  The big problem is hosting the application locally for every user.

Instead of using a web application, I would suggest using a windows application that connects to a remote database.  In the event that the remote DB cannot be reached, you can fallback to a local database (the sqllite db).  Then, when a connection is restored you can programatically sync the two db's.  This can be done by creating what is called "Occasionally Connected Applications".  Heres a good article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29459/Introduction-to-ADO-NET-Sync-Services