# Synchronizing storaged data between web forms application and mobile client

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, mobile, webforms, local-storage

**Context:**
I have a web forms application using the Entity Framework to store objects in the SQL Server Express LocalDB. To work offline on a mobile client's browser, i use a manifest file and need to synchronize the stored data.

**Approach:**
Like mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986550/web-forms-application-storing-data-offline-using-sqlite) stackoverflow article, i could use the local storage of a mobile browser, avoid creating a mobile app and thus could stay platform independent.

**Question:**
How could i achieve to synchronize and map the stored data of the SQL Server with the local storage easily?
Is there maybe another approach?

I'd appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My solution:** *by using Json.NET and IndexedDB*

An expensive way to solve my problem is using Json.NET library and IndexedDB (LocalStorage works too). 
I serialize the required objects in code-behind, pass them over an hidden field to javascript, deserialize them and use them as json-objects. For updating the SQL-db, i need to go the same way backwards.

*Not the best, but A solution*